# Eclipse for Java EE on Linux - cannot see Java EE projects?

Tags: linux, eclipse, ubuntu

I just installed eclipse indigo on Ubuntu. After, I went to install new software > WEB, XML, Java EE etc.

When I go to Eclipse plugins, I see they are installed.

But when I try to create a new eg Web Project, I cannot see it! The one and only point to choose is "create new > general > project". Nothing else!

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Are the JEE and Web perspectives available?

Comment: No nothing is available from this new installed. Very strange :(

Comment: Just download the Jee release :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though this does not answer the OP's question, I would recommend installing the latest Java EE version from [**here**](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/?osType=linux) :

`http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/?osType=linux`

Back to your question. Perhaps you could try re-starting eclipse with the `-clean` option just to make sure that it's not obsolete workspace metadata which is at fault. If that does not work, I would reiterate the original suggestion to download the Java EE version to save time.

(Please don't be offended, but to rule out the obvious, you must have restarted Eclipse after installing all the plugins ?)

Comment: ok download an reinstall manual was good. I first used `apt-get install eclipse`, which obvious is corrupt or so.